# Toolstripmenuitem click event

Tags: c#, winforms

I use this code to add an item to my menu:

```
private void oKToolStripMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(toolStripTextBox3.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a username in the textbox.", "Error");
        return;
    }
    var username = usernamesToolStripMenuItem1.DropDownItems.Add(toolStripTextBox3.Text);
    username.Name = toolStripTextBox3.Text;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Usernames.Add(toolStripTextBox3.Text);
    toolStripTextBox3.Clear();
}
```

How do I make/call it's click event? The goal is that when you click on a username, it fills it in a textbox. I was hoping there'd be a .selecteditem but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscribe to the `Click` event after creating the menu item.

You can do this on a single line:

```
username.Click += (s, e) => SomeTextBox.Text = "test";
```

Or create a separate method if that's easier for you to read:

```
private void oKToolStripMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    var username = usernamesToolStripMenuItem1.DropDownItems.Add(toolStripTextBox3.Text);
    username.Click += username_Click;
    ...
}

void username_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SomeTextBox.Text = "test";
}
```

Comment: I created the method, however it doesn't work when I re-open the application because it only calls username_Click when I add a username. How should I fix this? I want to to call username_Click each time I click on a username and not just when adding one.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've added another foreach loop to assign `username_Click` to the menuitems.

Answer (score 1):

You can create menu item first and then assign different events to it:

```
    private void addNameToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        var newItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(toolStripTextBox3.Text);
        newItem.Click +=new EventHandler(addedItemClickEvent);
        newItem.Name = toolStripTextBox3.Text;
        usernamesToolStripMenuItem1.DropDownItems.Add(newItem);
        //Properties.Settings.Default.Usernames.Add(toolStripTextBox3.Text);
        toolStripTextBox3.Clear();
    }
```

You can then analyze sender name to perform various actions:

```
    private void addedItemClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((sender as ToolStripMenuItem).Text);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the overload of `Add` method that accepts a `ToolStripItem` as input and create that item using `ToolStripLabel`'s constructor that receives a delegate as input:

```
private void oKToolStripMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(toolStripTextBox3.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a username in the textbox.", "Error");
        return;
    }

    var username = usernamesToolStripMenuItem1.DropDownItems.Add(
                         new ToolStripLabel(toolStripTextBox3.Text, (Image) null,
                         false, toolstrip_click));

    username.Name = toolStripTextBox3.Text;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Usernames.Add(toolStripTextBox3.Text);
    toolStripTextBox3.Clear();
}

void toolstrip_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(((ToolStripLabel)sender).Text);  // Write your code here
}
```