# menuStrip programally added dropdown item eventhandling?

Tags: listview, c#-4.0, drop-down-menu, event-handling, menustrip

menuStrip ->

```
for(int v = 0; v < vcount; v++) { toolStripMenuItem1.DropDownItems.Add("Volume #" + v); }
```

Now, having issues assigning button_Click eventhandler to the drop down menu.

Example :

```
for(int v = 0; v < vcount; v++) { toolStripMenuItem1.DropDownItems.Add("Volume #" + v.ToString(),v,<eventhandlergoeshere how?>); }
```

But how do I use it?
I mean what do I type to the 3rd section of DropDownItems.add(,,?) to raise an unique event for multiple items (lets say there's 3 volumes for loop goes thru)?

Answer (score 0):

Seems, my question is a duplicate as found 2 different kind of answers at this post:

[Toolstripmenuitem click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850705/toolstripmenuitem-click-event)

However, I still can't understand how I can assign number to click event or some sort of SelectedIndex how to determ which Volume # was clicked for the listing search to handle from the event.

Example:

```
    for (int v = 0; v < vcount; v++)
    {
        string Volumes_Counter = "0" + (v + 1).ToString();
        var prog_Items = toolStripMenuItem1.DropDownItems.Add("Volume #" + Volumes_Counter);
        prog_Items.Click += prog_Items_Click;
    }
    void prog_Items_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       search("volume1");
    }
```

So, wonder how I can pass the for loop counter to the eventhandler.